# ERRATA Different behavior for JMESpath on the jmeter extractor

Tags: json, regex, jmeter, jmespath

I'm trying to extract highest value on array containing Null values; jmeter doesn't doing  it, anyone know why?

using: max(result[].data[].values[]) works fine at https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html

ERROR o.a.j.e.j.j.JMESPathExtractor: Error processing JSON content in JSON JMESPath Extractor, message: Invalid argument type calling "max": expected array of number or string but was array containing array

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "metricId": "count.server",
            "data": [
                {
                    "dimensions": [
                        "SERVICE_METHOD"
                    ],
                    "dimensionMap": {
                        "dt.entity.service_method": "SERVICE_METHOD"
                    },
                    "values": [
                        null,
                        null,
                        1,
                        null,
                        null,
                        1,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        1,
                        1,
                        null,
                        null,
                        4,
                        null
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that the expression "works fine" as it produces something like:

[image]

So you need to:

1. Get rid of this nested [JSON Array](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp)
2. Get rid of these `null` entries

Example JMESPath query would be something like:

```
result[0].data[0].values[? @ != null] | max (@)
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [The JMeter JSON JMESPath Extractor and Assertion: A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-json-jmespath-extractor-andassertion-a-guide)

Comment: Sorry; the correct query is: max(result[].data[].values[])